# C++ Processing Cyrillic strings in English Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding, windows-server-2012-r2

I wrote the application which connects to Active Directory located on Windows Server 2012. At first application retrieves Organisation Units names from AD. Then it gets users from every Organization Unit, process them and send information to another webapp.

Organization Units and Users from AD can have names both in English and Russian.

So when I'm running my app in Windows with Russian system language all is goind good.

But when I'm trying to run it on Windows Server(or Windows 7 with English system language) I'm getting **sequences of "?" instead of Russian** strings both in:

1. Logfile
2. Console output
3. Active Directory search string, which contains name of Organization Unit

Inside application I tried to use `std::string` and `std::wstring` to hold extracted from Active Directory data and got the same result - "?" instead of Russian words.

Using MSVS 2013, Windows 8.1 on developer stand. And libLDAP(setting version 3) to connect to Active Directory.

What do I need to do to make my application correctly process Russian strings?

Comment: *"What do I need to do to make my application correctly process Russian strings?"* - You need to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). We have no idea, what character **encoding** you are using, and apparently, neither do you. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Windows 7 solution: [http://blooplace.eu/how-to-fix-cyrillic-text-on-windows-7/](http://blooplace.eu/how-to-fix-cyrillic-text-on-windows-7/)

Comment: @Rotem: That "solution" merely hides the real issue. It doesn't solve it. And the OP is well aware, that changing the system language will make the issue disappear. You need to understand character encodings, and which character encoding the particular library is using to produce a real solution, that doesn't rely on some random, external, environmental setting.

Comment: @Rotem: thanks, it really helps(and working on another platforms I guess). But I need(how was said before) to produce real solution

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you for article, it's very useful :-)

I use windows-1251 encoding on developer's stand. What is to do next?

Comment: It doesn't matter, what codepage you are using on your developer machine. What matters is the character encoding used by the AD server and the libLDAP library.

Comment: @IInspectable According to [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.1.2) libLDAP uses UTF-8 encoding for strings. Does that mean, that I should convert wchar_t* (which is result's type of ldap functions) to std::u8string and working with it?

Comment: If an LDAP call on Windows returns a `wchar_t*`, then you aren't dealing with UTF-8 encoding. `wchar_t` on Windows is UTF-16LE. `char` on Windows could be anything, UTF-8, ASCII, or ANSI/codepage encoding. You need to find out, which character encoding your strings are. Consult the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable Just found it! My strings have windows-1251(ansi/1251) encoding.

Comment: That sounds like you are sending LDAP v2 requests. This is explained under [LDPA Conformance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223226.aspx): *"When processing an LDAP v2 request, Active Directory exhibits the following behavioral differences from processing an LDAP v3 request: Instead of using the UTF-8 character encoding for LDAPString [RFC2251], the system's configured code page is used. The code page is configured locally on the DC by the DC's administrator."*

Comment: @IInspectable No, I'm setting option to use LDAP v3. `wchar_t *` strings, which are returned from ldap functions, contain utf-16 encoded characters(precisely, code points). But simple char* strings contains windows-1251 characters. To convert between string and wstring I use `WideCharToMultiByte`/`MultiByteToWideChar` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.
I used functions `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` always with `CP_ACP` as first argument. When I changed it to `CP_UTF8` everything went fine.

By the way, I also changed encoding of all project's files to UTF-8 without BOM.

@IInspectable, thank you for helping